# Why i get error when i try to run command play in python script of discord bot

Tags: python, ffmpeg

My code of music discord bot:

```python
import ffmpeg
import asyncio
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
import requests
import random
import json
from replit import db
import youtube_dl
from keep_alive import keep_alive

class music(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    async def join(self, ctx):
        if ctx.author.voice is None:
            await ctx.send(f'{ctx.message.author.mention}, Ты не подключён к голосовому чату!')
        voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        if ctx.voice_client is None:
            await voice_channel.connect()
        else:
            await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)
  
    @commands.command()
    async def leave(self, ctx):
        if ctx.author.voice is None:
            await ctx.send(f'{ctx.message.author.mention}, Ты не подключён к голосовому чату!')
        else:
            await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()
            await ctx.send(f'{ctx.message.author.mention}, Пока!')

    @commands.command()
    async def play(self, ctx, *, url):
        if ctx.author.voice is None:
            await ctx.send(f'{ctx.message.author.mention}, Ты не подключён к голосовому чату!')
        ctx.voice_client.stop()
        ffmpeg_options = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
        YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': 'bestaudio/best', 'noplaylist': 'True', 'simulate': 'True',
                       'preferredquality': '32bits', 'preferredcodec': 'wav', 'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio'}
        vc = ctx.voice_client

        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
            if 'https://' in url:
                info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
            else:
                info = ydl.extract_info(f'ytsearch:{url}', download=False)['entries'][0]
            url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
            source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, **ffmpeg_options)
            vc.play(source)

    @commands.command()
    async def pause(self, ctx):
        if ctx.author.voice is None:
            await ctx.send(f'{ctx.message.author.mention}, Ты не подключён к голосовому чату!')
            await ctx.voice_client.pause()
            await ctx.send(f'{ctx.message.author.mention}, Пауза')

    @commands.command()
    async def resume(self, ctx):
        if ctx.author.voice is None:
            await ctx.send(f'{ctx.message.author.mention}, Ты не подключён к голосовому чату!')
            await ctx.voice_client.resume()
            await ctx.send(f'{ctx.message.author.mention}, Играет')

#    @commands.command()
 #   async def stop(self, ctx):
  #      await ctx.voice_client.stop()
   #     ctx.send(f'{author.mention}, Остановлен')

#   @commands.command()
 #  async def repeat(self, ctx):
  #    await ctx.voice_client.repeat()
   #   ctx.send(f'{author.mention}, Повтор')

#   @commands.command()
 #  async def loop(self, ctx):
  #    await ctx.voice_client.loop()
   #   ctx.send(f'{author.mention}, Повтор')

keep_alive()
def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(music(client))
```

But i get error when i write in discord command play:

```python
[youtube] rUd2diUWDyI: Downloading webpage
[youtube] Downloading just video rUd2diUWDyI because of --no-playlist
[youtube] rUd2diUWDyI: Downloading webpage
[youtube] Downloading just video rUd2diUWDyI because of --no-playlist
Ignoring exception in command play:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/MBOT/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/MBOT/music.py", line 51, in play
    source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(url2, **ffmpeg_options)
  File "/home/runner/MBOT/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/player.py", line 387, in from_probe
    return cls(source, bitrate=bitrate, codec=codec, **kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/MBOT/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/player.py", line 324, in __init__
    super().__init__(source, executable=executable, args=args, **subprocess_kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/MBOT/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/player.py", line 138, in __init__
    self._process = self._spawn_process(args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/MBOT/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/player.py", line 147, in _spawn_process
    raise ClientException(executable + ' was not found.') from None
discord.errors.ClientException: ffmpeg was not found.
```

I try install ffmpeg in console python, but this dont helped me. Please, give me answer on my question. I use service replit.com to coding on python. Because i want to install this script on server. How i can solve this problem?

Comment: IIRC files added to the running environment don't persist on repl.it. Have you tried installing python locally?

Comment: Yes, i try start this code locally. In pycharm my code start without errors.